# Modifying a TDS Module for Higher Electrical Conductivity Measurements

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, water, conductivity, sensing

I recently acquired a Keyestudio V1.0 TDS module, primarily used for measuring the electrical conductivity of water. The module is recommended for 0-1000ppm or 0-2000μS/cm measurements. [image: Keyestudio V1.0 TDS module]

However, my goal is to modify this module to extend its measurement capability up to 20000μS/cm. I've been examining the circuit closely to identify potential modifications. Here is the revised schematic of the module: [image: Keyestudio V1.0 TDS Schematic revised]

In my analysis, I've attempted to identify the constituent functional blocks of the circuit. I'd like to confirm if my understanding is correct. Moreover, I'm particularly curious about the purpose of the circuit enclosed in the yellow square on the schematic.

Based on my understanding and previous experiments, I believe that modifying the circuit's measurement range might be achievable by replacing the R12 resistor with one of a smaller resistance. This should, in theory, adjust the module's sensitivity to higher conductivity levels.

**Questions:**

1. Is my interpretation of the circuit's functional blocks correct?
2. Can someone explain the function of the circuit within the yellow square?
3. Would replacing the R12 resistor effectively increase the measurement range as intended? If so, how can I calculate the appropriate value for the new resistor?

I'm open to any suggestions or insights that could help in successfully modifying this module.

Comment: I've never heard of keyestudio, but I looked at your pictures and your screenshot. I still have no idea what "TDS" stands for. Would you care to clarify?

Comment: TDS stands for 'Total Dissolved Solids', a crucial parameter in hydroponics, aquariums, and similar applications. TDS is closely correlated with the concentration of ions present in a solution and can be considered a rough measure of salinity. There is no simple method to measure tds directly. Instead the TDS module actually measures Electrical Conductivity (EC), which is indirectly related to TDS. EC is the reciprocal of resistivity (1/R = G) and is typically expressed in microsiemens per centimeter (μS/cm).

Comment: The measurement process involves introducing an alternating voltage into the sample solution. A current meter at the other end of the probe then measures the current passing through a specific length of water, usually 1 cm. The module assesses the resistance of the solution and converts this data into an analog voltage output, which correlates to the TDS level.